# Смена контента без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax, php, cms, html

Здравствуйте. Есть `cms amxbans` как сделать смену контента без перезагрузки страницы, выводом из других файлов.

Answer (score 4):

Смотри в сторону - JavaScript, jQuery, Ajax

Comment: я это знаю статью не подскажите?

Comment: @bajex здесь должен быть вопрос про то, умеете ли вы пользоваться Гуглом

Comment: Вы шутите? Вас забанили на гугле? Может не знаете, как [запрос составить][1]?

   [1]:http://bit.ly/17zmcaJ

Comment: @bajex, http://jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо использовать AJAX - запросы.

Код, который я использую для этих целей:

```
function send_request(r_method, r_path, r_args, r_handler)
{
    var Request = false;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        };
        catch(CatchException)
        {
            Request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    if(!Request)
    {
        return;
    }
    Request.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(Request.readyState==4)
            if(Request.status==200)
                r_handler(Request.responseText);
        if(r_method.toLowerCase() =="get"&&r_args.length>0)
            r_path+="?"+r_args;
        Request.open(r_method,r_path,true);
        if(r_method.toLowerCase()=="post")
        {
            Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            Request.send(r_args)
        }
        else
        {
            Request.send(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Коротко об аргументах:

```
send_request("Тип запроса. get либо post","Путь/к/файлу.php","Аргументы. Например: topic=46764&page=4",function(response){
    //Код, который будет исполняться при успешном окончании запроса
    //response - переменная, содержащая ответ      
})
```

Небольшой пример:

test.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function send_request(r_method, r_path, r_args, r_handler)
    {
        var Request = false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            try
            {
                Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }catch(CatchException)
            {
                Request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        if(!Request)
        {
            return;
        }
        Request.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(Request.readyState==4)
                if(Request.status==200)
                    r_handler(Request.responseText);
            if(r_method.toLowerCase() =="get"&&r_args.length>0)
                r_path+="?"+r_args;
            Request.open(r_method,r_path,true);
            if(r_method.toLowerCase()=="post")
            {
                Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
                Request.send(r_args)
            }
            else
            {
                Request.send(null)
            }
        }
    }
    function request() {
      send_request("GET", "test.php", "testval=test", function(response) {
          document.body.innerHTML+=response
      })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="request()">Загрузить!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

test.php

```
<?PHP
echo "Тестовая переменная: ".$_GET['testvar'];
?>
```

Переменных можно добавлять неограниченное количество. Смену контента можно сделать, заставив PHP-скрипт отдавать html-код, и позднее изменять innerHTML какого-либо блока на response. Этот вариант самый простой. Есть вариант посложнее, с JSON, но это уже другой вопрос.